# Logout from facebook.com invalidates access token in my app

Tags: access-token, facebook-ios-sdk

I've just realized that if I log out from facebook.com, the access token in my app is no longer valid (`fbSessionInvalidated` gets called).

I don't understand why logging out from the Facebook **website** would invalidate the access token **in my app**. Is this normal behaviour, and if so why is it happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just enabled "Remove offline_access permission" in my app's advanced settings and this problem is fixed (I also get 60 days access tokens now).

Answer (score 0):

it's normal, you need to ask a offline token.

But be carefull Since 2nd of may.

This is in place http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: offline_access is deprecated, so obviously I'm not going to use it. But this is not what I'm asking anyway. Just want to understand why logging out of the FB website invalidates the access token in my app too.

Comment: you have to ask a different kind of token read the documentation, it explain how to work w/out offline token so you will avoid your token expires.I mean check there is 5 scenario to workaround, I had the same issue as you and that's the way to do.

Comment: and this is a nice tools to understand how all of this works.https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token?q=